# Change color of marker-end on mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to select a `marker` to change the color of it while `mouseover` is on a particular arrow head. On `mouseover` I want all the other nodes and arrows to fade down.

I tried to use `d3.selectAll("#arrowhead").style("fill","#BFC3E1");`, 
but it didn't work.

My code is here http://plnkr.co/edit/EvpNC6B5DBWczNXKiL82?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the color of the same marker individually to correspond to the color of the line dynamically. The only way to do it is to create separate markers and give them separate `id`s.

Then you can target them and change the colors on the fly.